# Rails: Find users where the user id is stored in a associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I need to get a list of users from a associated table.

From, for example 35 users, i need just these users, like below in the screenshot.

[image]

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applicants
  has_many :users, through: :applicants
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applicants
  has_many :books, through: :applicants
end

class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

How is the way to get the user records out of the `applicants` table?

Comment: What exactly is the input? An array of `user_ids`, `application_ids`, `book_ids`, or an array of `applicants`? An SQL query that returned the above list?

Comment: Actually there is noSQL query. I'm looking for exactly that. At the end i want to have a array of users to work with in the views.

Comment: So, you want to just query for _those particular users_? You can use `User.where(id: 1.upto(11).to_a`. Or is there some other logic you're using to get this list? We can show you how to write the query, but we don't know _what_ logic you need.

Comment: So you want to have a list of all users that have at least one book? Or a specific book? Or were in the list of the first 11 applicants?

Comment: The solution came from @Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users that have applicants:

`User.joins(:applicants).all`

Bonus: Users that have no applicants:

`User.left_outer_joins(:applicants).where(applicants: { id: nil })`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to clarify the question a bit more. The screenshot, you have posted, how did you filter your table? Is it the first 11 ids from applicants? If you want all users that are present in applicants, you can run - `User.joins(:applicants).all`

Or if you simply want all users, you can run `User.all`

Comment: Thanks @Rahul
That was what i was looking for ;)

Comment: yes i saw this and changed it in my code, it worked fine